# Is there a C++ function to turn off the computer?

Tags: c++, windows, application-shutdown

Is there a C++ function to turn off the computer?  And since I doubt there is one (in the standard library, at least), what's the windows function that I can call from C++?

Basically, what is the code to turn off a windows xp computer in c++?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

On windows you can use the ExitWindows function described here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376868(VS.85).aspx

and here's a link to example code that does this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376871(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 6):

Use the following, assuming you have the privileges):

```
ExitWindowsEx (EWX_POWEROFF | EWX_FORCEIFHUNG,
    SHTDN_REASON_MINOR_OTHER);
```

This will cause power off while giving applications a chance to shut down (if they take too long, they'll be terminated anyway).

It's part of the Win32 API rather than standard C++ but that's because C++ provides no way to do this directly.

Answer (score 4):

You can shutdown by utilizing the system() function.

for Windows

```
system("shutdown -s");
```

for Linux

```
system("poweroff");
```

or

```
system("init 0");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in Windows, by calling the [`ExitWindowsEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376868(VS.85).aspx) function.

Answer (score 0):

yes!
for Windows XP:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   char ch;

   printf("Do you want to shutdown your computer now (y/n)\n");
   scanf("%c", &ch);

   if (ch == 'y' || ch == 'Y')
       system("C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\shutdown -s");
       return 0;
}
```

For Windows 7

```
system("C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\shutdown /s");
```

For Linux

```
system("shutdown -P now");
```

Comment: Can you edit your proposed answer to expand on what this does and how it addresses the OP?

Answer (score 0):

**[ FOR WINDOWS ]**

None of other solutions worked for me, I wanted to shutdown my customized windows and without explorer this codes simply don't work.

The important note is **timeout time**, so here's the real solution for windows :

```
GenericFunction(void, Shutdown)()
{
    WinExec("shutdown -s -t 0", SW_HIDE);
    Sleep(500); // Works without this but it's safer to use sleep
    KillProcessTree("winlogon"); // Internal process killer you can use pskill64
    // WinExec("pskill64 winlogon -t -nobanner /accepteula", SW_HIDE);
    exit(-10); // Planned Shutdown Code
}
```

Comment: What part of `ExitWindowsEx` didn't work for you? Did you pass the `EWX_FORCEIFHUNG` flag, as advised in the documentation? Shelling out to stuff like `shutdown` is a really bad solution, and offers nothing that the API calls directly don't offer.

Comment: `ExitWindowsEx` doesn't work on customized windows using WinPE or mods.