# Qt shutdown() not working on deployed applications

Tags: c++, qt, shutdown, qt5

I made a program that will shutdown PC after a set time.
User enters time using 2 spin boxes (one for hours and the other for minutes), 
then i convert it to miliseconds:

```
ms = (ui->hBox->text().toInt() * 3600 + ui->mBox->text().toInt() * 60) * 1000;
```

then it calls timer() function

```
void Dialog::timer()
{
    QTimer *time = new QTimer(this);
    time->setInterval(ms);
    time->setSingleShot(1);
    connect(time, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(shutdown()));
    time->start();
}
```

then signal timeout() calls shutdown() slot/function that check whether user want to shutdown, restart or log off PC and then executes appropriate command.

```
void Dialog::shutdown()
{
    if(ui->radioButton->isChecked())
        system("shutdown -s -t 0");
    else if(ui->radioButton_2->isChecked())
        system("shutdown -r -t 0");
    else if(ui->radioButton_3->isChecked())
        system("shutdown -l -t 0");
}
```

(also tried "shutdown -s -f", and even only "shutdown -s", nothing seems to help resolve problem)

I want to run this application only on my Windows PC, so using system() is not problem either.

The above application executes perfectly when i run it from Qt Creator, but when I deploy it, put all needed .dll files, the program wait for timer and then just opens empty console and then launch new instance of the program, PC never turn off or restart.
So what am I doing wrong? Am I missing some .dll files or something?

Comment: Have you use Dependency walker to check any missing dll?

Comment: Yes, I did, it reports that I have everything. I needed to put icudt49, icuin49, icuuc49, libEGL, libgcc_s_sjlj-1, libGLESv2, libstdc++-6, libwinpthread, Qt5Core, Qt5Gui, Qt5Widgets, and platforms folder with qwindows.dll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple fix is to rename your deployed exe to something like: *shut*.exe or anything instead of *shutdown*.exe, then the system will execute it's *shutdown* command instead of executing your application again.

LE: there might be other ways to solve this, but i haven't investigated this... so stay close for other solutions too ;)

Comment: Thank you so much, I would never think of that solution. I don't even know why was I so dumb to think calling it shutdown.exe was a good idea in the first place. At least now I will never forget that for the rest of my life.

Answer (score 0):

Using system() is insecure. A much better solution to your problem is to use the Win32 API call ExitWindowEx().

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376868(v=vs.85).aspx

Of course since this is windows only you'd have to #ifdef it for the windows platform.

```
#ifdef Q_OS_WIN
#include "qt_windows.h"
if ( !ExitWindowsEx(EWX_SHUTDOWN,0)) // Or EWX_FORCE
{
  // Failed, call GetLastError() to know why
}
#endif
```

Edit: You also need the correct privilege:

[How to turn off pc via windows API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503839/how-to-turn-off-pc-via-windows-api)

Comment: It doesn't seem to do anything, not even when I run program from Qt Creator. I included <windows.h>, do I need to do anything else?

Comment: What is the return value of ExitWindowsEx?

Comment: Ok, so I read that and it says "the calling process must use the AdjustTokenPrivileges function to enable the SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME privilege." and I have no idea what all that means and how to use it. Can you tell me specifically what should I type to resolve my problem? Maybe it's trivial for you but it is very hard for me to understand.

Comment: If you check the linked question there is an answer which provides a full function to do this. MSDN will explain the details of what each API is doing, but it boils down to the fact that you require a certain OS privilege to be able to shut the OS down.