# Windows Logoff Event c++

Tags: c++, windows, events

I need to catch windows logoff event, I'm using c++. I dont know where to start searching,

thanks for any help,

Dani.

Comment: I think [this link][1] might help you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16169305/windows-logoff-capture-with-c/24134430#24134430

Comment: Duplicate of [Old Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/846576/is-there-a-c-function-to-turn-off-the-computer)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In console application, you can register a callback ([`SetConsoleCtrlHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686016.aspx), [`CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683242.aspx)).

In message-loop application, you can catch certain messages ([`WM_QUERYENDSESSION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376890.aspx), [`WM_ENDSESSION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376889.aspx)).

See [Logging Off (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376876.aspx) on MSDN.

Answer (score 4):

[WM_QUERYENDSESSION and WM_ENDSESSION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376890%28VS.85%29.aspx) are most likely what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the "correct" way is to listen to a WMI event.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/0c1bded8-0cce-4260-bd28-4b4ffce0d27d

Disclaimer: I have not tried this myself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use OpenInputDesktop [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684309(VS.85).aspx)

During logoff, the Input Desktop is inaccessible to the user, and the function retuns NULL.

ex:
HDESK hDesk = OpenInputDesktop(0, FALSE, READ_CONTROL);

if (!hDesk)
   -- during logoff... --
else
{
   --normal state--
   CloseHandle(hDesk);
}

In windows vista & 7, pressing CTRL+ALT+DELETE also brings to an inaccessible to the user desktop.